# Has Israel interfered in US Elections?

Tags: united-states, politics, israel

So I came upon this [July 2018 Independent article](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/israel-us-elections-intervention-russia-noam-chomsky-donald-trump-a8470481.html) which quotes social critic [Noam Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky) as saying that Israel interfered in US election(s):

> Veteran activist Noam Chomsky has accused Israel of “brazenly” interfering in US electoral politics in a way that vastly outweighs any efforts that may have been carried out by Russia.

However the only example he cites is Netenyahu addressing congress without informing President Obama.

> “Israeli intervention in US elections vastly overwhelms anything the Russians may have done, I mean, even to the point where the prime minister of Israel, Netanyahu, goes directly to Congress, without even informing the president, and speaks to Congress, with overwhelming applause, to try to undermine the president’s policies - what happened with Obama and Netanyahu in 2015.”

*The Independent* are quoting from [Chomsky's interview with *Democracy Now*](https://www.democracynow.org/2018/7/27/noam_chomsky_on_mass_media_obsession).

Has there been any interference that backs up this claim?

Only thing I came across was the voting machines, but that appears to just be a conspiracy theory with no backing as far as I can see.

The [New York Post](https://nypost.com/2018/05/23/the-hypocrisy-of-american-election-investigations-into-israel/) also claims that Special Council Robert Mueller has sent investigators to Israel to look into interference, but again does not say how or why anything is suspect.

After further research,

According to The [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/19/us/politics/trump-jr-saudi-uae-nader-prince-zamel.html) and [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/may/19/donald-trump-jr-meeting-saudi-arabia-united-arab-emirates-report), which used New York times as a reference, Mueller is investigating an August 2016 meeting between Donald Trump Jr. and "a firm who specialized in data collection and social media persuasion." The firm employed  "employed several Israeli former intelligence " to whom it appears large sums of money were transferred after the election

I cannot find if any statement from the probe has been made or the status of this probe/investigation.

So for the sake of this question I will limit "*interference*"  to social media manipulation for the purpose of electing Donald Trump.

Comment: I think Chomsky is referring to something entirely different from the accusations against Russia, i.e. going places and giving speeches and encouraging Americans to vote for Israeli-friendly candidates.

Comment: The term "interference" is awfully vague and subjective, and I don't think we can answer the title question "has Israel interfered" in an objective way according to this site's standards.  If you can find specific things they're alleged to have done (maybe in the full interview?) we could help to determine whether or not they happened.  But whether they constitute "interference" is a question best left to Politics.SE instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge - I agree with the first part of your comment fully, but your second part is wrong. Using more colloquial wording from some CMs/mods on the rules for migration, "don't migrate garbage". If the question is too subjective for answering here, it's 100% equally as subjective for answering on Politics.SE.

Comment: My impression is that Politics.SE has rather different standards than we do.  A great many highly-voted questions over there would immediately get closed here as too subjective.  But I don't have a lot of experience on that site, perhaps you know better.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have narrowed the scope with additional articles detailing what the special council is investigating.

Comment: But now the claim is not notable.  Chomsky was claiming that Netanyahu's speech was, in and of itself, interference that was greater than Russia's social media manipulation.  That you have misinterpreted that to refer to social media manipulation by Israel makes that your claim, not that of the notable source Chomsky.

Comment: @Brythan I took Chomsky's quote to refer to doing more in the way of interference not specifically that the speech itself was of greater significance. So social media manipulation would just be one of the subsets of things that were done along with the speech and maybe other things, however it appears that only the social media manipulation is being investigated

Comment: This question would be much better asked on Politics.SE where it's likely on topic. On skeptics though it won't work because it's based on interpreting correctly the words of Chomsky.